# Kiel traduki "slot machine" esperante?

Tags: single-word-requests

Mi volas traduki "slot machine" en esperanto. Mi trovis la vortojn "ludmaŝino" kaj "monludmaŝino" en la retejo de Glosbe. Ĉu ili taŭgas (eble estas tro ĝeneralaj)? Ĉu estas alia opcio?

[image]

Bildo: Yamaguchi先生, CC BY-SA 3.0 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/, Wikimedia Commons

Comment: Aŭtomate mi pensis, ke temas pri "ludaŭtomato". Kp. "monaŭtomato".

Comment: _slot machine_ laŭtlitere signifas _moneraŭtomato_, kie _slot_ estas longrektangula truo por enmeti la monerojn. Tamen tio estas specifa anglismo. En la germana kaj nederlanda estas _ludaŭtomato_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por aldoni ankoraŭ alian proponon, la [vortaro de John Wells](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) havas ĉi tion:

> **slot machine** (vend-, vet-)aŭtomato

Eble la unua propono *vendaŭtomato* temas pri alia afero per kiu oni povas simple aĉeti aferojn. La propono *vetaŭtomato* ŝajnas taŭga por ĉi tiu afero, kaj ĝi estas kvazaŭ kombino de la proponoj de Paul kaj Juha.

Comment: Jes, mi samopinias, ke _vetaŭtomato_ estas plej taŭga, ĉar fakte la formo de ludado estas veto.

Answer (score 2):

Mi ankaŭ proponus eble "vet-maŝino".

Sed pli ĝenerale, mi dirus ke tio ĉi estas perfekta ekzemplo de tio ke oni ne devas ĉiam havi en Esperanto unu precizan kaj unikan terminon. La kunteksto, kombinite kun la logiko de la vorto-partoj sendube trafos perfekte la celitan ideon sendepende de kiu el la proponitaj vortoj oni elektus.